# How to use require or import and not balise html

Tags: node.js, electron, node-webkit, pixi.js, nwjs

I test many paths, I install npm pixi.js on many folders and the default folder, ESLint doesn't see my error because he doesn't see my library, I want to change script library js to import or require, but nothing work...

I test all paths, and I test many ways.

Look at my screen, and thanks to you

<3

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR2MY.png)

Answer (score 0):

In NW.js you would just do

`const PIXI = require('pixi.js');`

Assuming you did `npm install --save pixi.js`